# Dynamically generated divs on the same line with predefined parent width and horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following problem:

I have a form that uploads some pictures. After uploading them I want to display their thumnail into a div with the width of 200px with an horizontal scroll. When the width of my div is reached the thumnails go on the next line.

Please can anybody help me!

JS

```
function updatepic(pic) {
             var photos = document.querySelector("#photos");

             var frame = document.createElement("DIV");
             frame.setAttribute("class" , "frame");
             photos.appendChild(frame);

             var img = document.createElement("IMG");
             img.setAttribute("id" , "img");             
             img.setAttribute("src" , pic);          
             frame.appendChild(img);        

        }
```

HTML

```
<form id="form" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="iframe">
        Choose U're file!
        <input id="file" name="file" type="file"> </input>      
        <br/>
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="UPLOAD"></input>

</form>


        <div id="photos"></div>
```

CSS

```
#photos {
        display:inline-block;       
        position: absolute;
        top: 35%;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y : hidden;        
    }

.frame {

        float: left;        
        margin-top: 3%;
        margin-left: 2%;        
        max-height: 80%;        
        border: 2px solid black;
        background-color: black;
    }


    #img {
        display: inline;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 80%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to disable wrapping in the div. add this style to #photos css.

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

remove `float:left` from .frame and make it display:inline-block or inline so that all frames can be shown on one line.

A side note: since multiple images would be there, you should not use id "img" and css selector #img. 
Rather use `.frame > img` or define a class on image element.

Comment: check my updated answer. you should also use overflow-x auto instead of scroll so that scroll bar is shown only when required.

Answer (score -1):

Internet Explorer 8 and earlier do not support the SetAttribute Method.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

You can use:

```
frame.style.whiteSpace="nowrap";
```

in the script.

Comment: Who said anything about IE8 and older?  Also, your statement isn't true.  IE 8 and older do support setAttribute.  However, in IE7 and older, setAttribute can't be used to set the style attribute.  For future reference, don't use w3schools.  They got this (and many other things) wrong.  Here's a much better resource: http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/

Comment: Thanks for the input, will use quirksmode.org from now on.